# passing current_user to model via callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, virtual-attribute

I have a couple of callbacks that log activity on create/update:

```
class Projelement
  ..
  after_create   { |p| p.log_projelement_activity "created" }
  after_update   { |p| p.log_projelement_activity "edited"  }
```

I need to augment the design to pass the `current_user` (Devise) to `log_projelement_activity` to record the user at the time of create/update.

I'm trying to pass the `current_user` from the controller to the model and the callbacks via a virtual attribute. But this isn't working.

The code:

```
class Projelement
  attr_accessor :modifying_user

  after_create   { |p| p.log_projelement_activity "created", modifying_user }
  after_update   { |p| p.log_projelement_activity "edited",  modifying_user }

  def log_projelement_activity(op_type, user)
    @a = Activity.new
    @a.user = user
  end
end


class MilestoneController
  ..
  def create
    @milestone = Milestone.new(params[:milestone])
    @milestone.modifying_user = current_user
  end
end
```

Each create/update `Activity` has expected values, except that the `user` field is `nil`.

What am I missing?

Comment: You mean `Projelement.new`, right? Try adding user to `params`, `@milestone = Projelement.new(params[:milestone].merge(:modifying_user => current_user))`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm instantiating a ``Milestone`` which is a type of ``Projelement``. This has a few extra attributes and all other attributes are being set properly except for ``modifying_user``. Unfortunately your suggestion didn't work: how is it different to what I am doing before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [userstamp](https://github.com/delynn/userstamp). I think that this gem does exactly what you need ;) I used it with devise and it... just works perfectly!

Comment: Thanks @santuxus. Have been looking through it: finding it a bit hard understanding the usage as it's written a bit abstractly. Am also using ``Mongoid``. It does seem to be used by a lot of people.

Comment: https://github.com/msaffitz/userstamp-mongoid should be for you. I haven't used it and the main repo is 2-years-old, but I suppose one of the forks should be ok and up to date.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I was googling around and found it too